How to create external soft start for a BTS FET?
I want to create a hardware solution. The datasheet is here.
The circuit is shown below. I do not have access to the code in order to implement a soft start using a PWM. Is there a way I can create a soft start using hardware components so the BTS turns on "slowly", rather than quickly?
I want to avoid having any spikes when I turn the BTS on, hence the soft start.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

You could attempt to control the voltage on Vbb, so that it ramps up after the GPIO has been asserted.

@Aaron how would I do this?

This may help with the concept: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294061/p-channel-mosfet-inrush-current-limiting

What rate do you need? How does it compare with the rates in the datasheet? What about current limit (is the load capacitive?)?

BTS is a FET transistor with integrated  logic. The logic will not allow you to slowly close or open transistor and it doesn't matter which method ( PWM or some hardware solution) you will use.
I would  propose you a few solutions:

Use normal P-MOSFET transistor instead BTS. In that case you will have access to gate of the transistor to slow down closing, but you will have to design driver and all protections offered by BTS.
You can use NTC Inrush Current Limiter. Such limiter has several ohms resistance which dropp when NTC will heat up. Drawback of this solution is that small current will not heat up NTC enough to decrease resistance.
You can add additional transistor in series which will be use for soft start only.

I have to warn you, that low open or close speed of a transistor will cause significant heating of the transistor. You need consider how much energy you can dissipated otherwise the transistor can get burned.
